# No sound from speakers after upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, sound

Sound settings only has "Dummy Output". See screenshot:

[image: Sound settings screenshot]

I have tried all the things that were mentioned in the previous posts regarding this issue but nothing worked for me. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
alsactl restore
```

May fix your issue.Add the command to your startup application list so that you can avoid entering the command each time you login to Ubuntu.